# How to pass arguments in dockerfile during docker run command

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am new in docker. For learning purpose, I'm working on code submission platform (online judge). So, I know at high level that whenever a user submit a code, it will hit an API which will receive code, languageID and inputs(if any), and this code will run on a docker container and return the output at the client side(or error if any).

Dockerfile :

```
FROM gcc:latest

COPY main.cpp /usr/src/cpp_test/prog.cpp

WORKDIR /usr/src/cpp_test/

CMD [ "sh", "-c", "g++ -o Test prog.cpp && ./Test" ]
```

So, whenever user submit a code, Everytime, I am first building this dockerfile(`docker build`) because main.cpp file will be different everytime and then running the `docker run` command.

So, my question is, Is there any way that I build this dockerfile only once(by making it more general) and now whenever a user submit a code, I just only need to run the `docker run` command.
Remember, there are 3 arguments that I have to pass ie., code, languageID, inputs(if any) to dockerfile.

Any help will be appreciated.
Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

First, looking at your existing Dockerfile: the output of `docker build` is an image containing a compiled, ready-to-run binary.  The image you have now contains a compiler plus a source file, but you'd generally have a compiled binary.  (If you're used to a compiler like `g++`, think of `docker build` as the same sort of sequence: it creates a directly runnable image and doesn't need copy of the source or to be rebuilt.)  So I'd typically `RUN g++`, not defer it until container startup:

```sh
FROM gcc:latest
WORKDIR /usr/src/cpp_test
COPY main.cpp .
RUN g++ -o Test main.cpp
CMD [ "./Test" ]
```

Even for the higher-level workflow you describe, I'm not sure I'd stray too far from this Dockerfile.  It doesn't do a whole lot beyond running the compiler and then creating a runnable image; so long as the source file is named `main.cpp` and it doesn't have any library dependencies this will work for any C++ source file.

---

If you really wanted to build and run an arbitrary source file without building an image per submission, you can use the unmodified `gcc` image here; you don't need a custom image since it won't really do anything.  I'd suggest writing a launcher shell script:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
set -e
g++ -o Test main.cpp
./Test
```

Create an execution directory:

```sh
mkdir run_1
cp -a launcher.sh run_1
cp submission_1.cpp run_1/main.cpp
```

Then run the container against that tree:

```sh
docker run --rm \
  -v "$PWD/run_1:/code" \
  -w /code \
  gcc:latest \
  ./launcher.sh
```

Comment: (Also remember that Docker is somewhat minimal protection against actually untrusted code: something running in the container can try to exploit kernel vulnerabilities, or do things like unwanted cryptocurrency mining that aren't attacks on the host _per se_.)